# Web.xml error while adding servlet mapping

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>DBTest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.package1.Test</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Test</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The servlet `Test.java` is in

```
src/com.package1/Test.java
```

Also

`WebContent/Login.jsp` has

```
<form method="POST" action="../Test">

</form>
```

When I add the servlet mapping in web.xml and run on server, it cannot connect to localhost.

Comment: does the server throw any errors?

Comment: Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Project1' did not find a matching property.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's just a warning.

Comment: Your server is not coming up with these changes or your form submit is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to save the complied copy of servlet (.class) in WEB-INF/classes folder....
And also check the CLASSPATH is set or not for servlet and jsp 
it seem like this \tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar and tomcat\lib\jsp-api.jar